# File transfers cause SSLv3 read error bad record mac to personal cloud

Tags: openssl, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, certificate, owncloud

This error also occurs when using webDav and also the build in web-browser uploader.

When I start the sync client with no upload limit, any file over 50 or so megabytes size produces the following error. Uploads work on some computers and not others with opensssl versions listed below.

> 11-27 19:12:36:292 0xd0c6f0 void Mirall::AbstractNetworkJob::slotFinished() 99 "Error while reading: error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record mac"

No matter how many times it is tried to be uploaded, it cannot be uploaded. Without an upload speed cap, the upload is at about 3MB/s and it errors. When I lower the upload speed limit to 1MB/s, all files upload normally. Somethings, it spews an "Unknown error", but when it retries, it works. Downloads work perfecly fine, the problem is only with uploads.

May be useful as the error is ssl related:

- The openssl version of the non-working is 1.0.1f-ubuntu2.7
- The openssl version of the working is 1.0.1e-3ubuntu1.6

The server setup is

Operating system:

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Kernel: Linux 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Openssl: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Web server:

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built: Jul 22 2014 14:36:38

Database:

mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

PHP version:

PHP: version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5.

Comment: client comes with its own lib so so I suppose those two different openssl versions you're mentioning are on the server? so you are using two different servers which are the same except for the openssl? what version of the owncloud client do you use?

Comment: Having the same issues, unfortunately not just with owncloud but with all programs that involve uploading files.

I have tried changing ciphers and protocol versions to see if some of my programs or browsers were not supporting new versions.

Nothing seems to be working, have you been able to resolve this issue?